# Is it possible to create a 3d scanner using ARcore depth api. Can a 3d model be constructed from collected point cloud?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I am planning on creating a 3d scanner using ARcore depth api. What I have on my mind is rendering a mesh on only a particular area on the world using a wireframe cube like scalable model to specify area to depth scan. And then collecting point data that comes from depth api from inside that restricted space.

I have seen something similar in vuforia, where an object is surrounded by a parabolic structure and the a 3d model of the object inside that structure is created.

Is it possible using ARcore?

Comment: have you found any answer?